# Style's CardBackgroundColor not working on CardView

Tags: android, layout, android-theme, android-styles

I can't work out why my CardView doesn't get the background color set by my style. According to this answer on another StackOverflow question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58270201/9275661) using the old AndroidSupport-library you should just be able to set it by adding this to the default AppTheme:

```xml
<item name="cardBackgroundColor">#ff00ab</item>
```

However, this doesn't change the color in any way for me. Normally setting the color through `app:cardBackgroundColor="..."` works fine, but for my application I need it to work through the styles.

I also tested it using a new project and just adding the minimal steps to make it work, but it still doesn't have the card color set by the style...

Here is my `activity_main.xml`:

```xml
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="testing string"/>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

In my `styles.xml` I've added the simple line above to the default Base application theme.

Thanks for any help solving my problem!

*EDIT*:
The AppTheme is just the default AppTheme with the line added above. It finally looks like this:

```xml
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="cardBackgroundColor">#ff00ab</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Did you apply the style to your **CardView**?

Comment: It is being applied to the whole activity using `android:theme` in the Manifest. Applying it directly onto the CardView in the layout doesn't make any difference. @DebarshiBhattacharjee

Comment: Can you show your app theme code??

Comment: @DebarshiBhattacharjee Added it to the description.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For me, what you've posted works on API 19 and 22, but does not work on API 28. The following works for me on all API levels:

Rather than defining `cardBackgroundColor` in your app's theme, instead define `cardViewStyle`. This is a "default" style that is applied to all CardViews (unless explicitly overridden by a `style` attribute in the layout file).

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    ...
    <item name="cardViewStyle">@style/MyCardViewStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyCardViewStyle">
    <item name="cardBackgroundColor">#ff00ab</item>
</style>
```

You can determine whether a widget supports a default style attribute by checking its source code. There will be a constructor that looks like this:

```
public CardView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, R.attr.cardViewStyle);
}
```

Here, the third param is `R.attr.cardViewStyle`, so we know that that's what our theme should define. For components that do not support default styles, this third parameter will be `0` instead.

Answer (score 1):

you can create your own style in styles.xml like this

```
<style name="card_view_style">
    <item name="cardBackgroundColor">#ff00ab</item>
</style>
```

and then apply this style to your card view like this

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    style="@style/card_view_style"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
```